# Water falling on top of central AC

Tags: air-conditioning, noise-reduction

So I have an AC unit outside my room onto which a whole bunch of water falls from straight from the gutter. Will this ruin the unit? Also, it makes A LOT of noise. What would be the best way to dampen that?

[image: Water falling on AC]

Comment: Gutters should direct water to the ground and away from your house, not onto the AC unit. Sounds like yours need cleaning.

Comment: Unfortunatley it's not my property and it is not a matter of cleaning. The thing was designed that way. Can I do anything about it?

Comment: @ovatsug25:  Probably no one would mind if the gutter were cleaned and/or repaired.  Gutters should not drip.  Why do you say "it is not a matter of cleaning"?

Answer (score 2):

The outdoor units are meant to have water hit them.  Only a flood or major major standing water would hurt the unit - unless the water came down at such a high rate that it bent something.

Go outside and look at your unit.  It will have a "section" or box with the electrical compontnents.  It would basically have to flood to that height to hurt your unit.

Water could have a good impact in that it would cool your unit and clean off dirt and small debris.  I can't really see how this would hurt anything.

Comment: The power of water has carved grand canyons through the face of the earth over time. While normal rainfall, or an occasional splash won't damage the unit.  A steady stream (or drip) in the same place over a long period of time, could potentially cause damage to the unit.

Comment: @Tester101 - I have had to replace some capacitors and wiring on units because they had rusted out because of standing water nearby.